# Access geojson property of a layer in a featuregroup in Mapbox

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I have a GEOJSON which I added to the featuregroup in my Mapbox map like this:

```
var featureCollection = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [0, 0]
    }
  },{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "id": 2
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [30, 30]
    }
  },{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "id": 3
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-30, -30]
    }
  }]
};
var geojson = L.geoJson(featureCollection);
var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
featureGroup.addLayer(geojson);
```

Now, I wish to access the id property of each layer while looping through the featuregroup, so that I can pass it as an argument to another function. In the case of a featurelayer, I can easily access it using something like this:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(featureCollection).addTo(map);
featureLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  layer.on('click', function (e) {
    console.log('Clicked feature ID: ' + e.target.feature.properties.id);
  });
});
```

But I want to be able to access it while looping inside a featuregroup, and also I want to be able to do it without a 'click' or any such event. For example, ideally I would use something like this:

```
featureGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  var id = layer.feature.properties.id;
  testfunction(id);
});
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. I've tried searching online, but because I'm new to this, I probably haven't been using the right keywords in my search.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or another example demo site when we can see this in action, because your proposed loop should work fine.

Comment: This is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8rd1x3p/1/) of what I'm trying to do. For some reason, the map is not showing up. But anyways, when I try this, it just tells me that layer.feature is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geojson` is nested within `featureGroup`, so when your `eachLayer` function runs, it is not operating on the individual features within `geojson`, but instead on `geojson` itself. To extract each feature's `id` property, you will need to go one level deeper and iterate over the features within `geojson`.

Fortunately, [the `L.GeoJson` class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) also supports the `eachLayer` method (because it is an extension of `L.FeatureGroup`, which is itself an extension of `L.LayerGroup`). To print the `id` of each feature, you could just use the `eachLayer` method directly on `geojson`:

```js
geojson.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  var id = layer.feature.properties.id;
  testfunction(id);
});
```

Or, if you have a bunch of `L.GeoJson` objects nested within `featureGroup`, you can use:

```js
featureGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    var id = layer.feature.properties.id;
    testfunction(id);
  });
});
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thanks a lot!